# Reordering dataframe with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

This is my current code to custom order a dataframe:

```
mtcars %>%
mutate(cyl = factor(cyl, levels = c(8, 6, 4))) %>%
arrange(cyl) %>%
dplyr::select(cyl)

    cyl
1    8
2    8
3    8
4    8
5    8
6    8
7    8
8    8
9    8
10   8
11   8
12   8
13   8
14   8
15   6
16   6
17   6
18   6
19   6
20   6
21   6
22   4
23   4
24   4
25   4
26   4
27   4
28   4
29   4
30   4
31   4
32   4
```

However, this code feels convoluted for what seems a fairly simple task. I was hoping `order_by` would do the trick, but this code fails to work as hoped:

```
mtcars %>%
mutate(cyl = order_by(cyl, c(8, 6, 4))) %>%
dplyr::select(cyl)

   cyl
1    8
2   NA
3   NA
4   NA
5   NA
6   NA
7   NA
8   NA
9   NA
10  NA
11  NA
12  NA
13  NA
14  NA
15  NA
16  NA
17  NA
18  NA
19  NA
20  NA
21  NA
22  NA
23  NA
24  NA
25  NA
26  NA
27  NA
28  NA
29  NA
30  NA
31  NA
32  NA
```

Can `order_by` achieve what I need?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort by a specific variable e.g. mpg, why not to use bracket approach:

```
table = mtcars %>%
mutate(cyl = factor(cyl, levels = c(8, 6, 4))) %>%
arrange(cyl)

table[order(table$mpg),]
```

Comment: I'm trying to reduce the amount of code not increase it!

Comment: So you should probably edit your question. It is not clear what is your desired output. order_by gives you NA's because you put a dataframe as an argument. The argument should be vector.

Comment: Top dataframe is desired output. I've got `cyl` as argument, which is a vector not a dataframe, so that isn't problem